# How to add current date and time to a cell with a button?

Tags: excel, vba, button

I wrote code in VBA Excel for a button to increment value in certain cell starting from 0.

The second feature of this button should be that, current date and time be shown in the A column starting from A2
[image]

If value in "L13" is 1, current date and time should appear in "A2", if value in "L13"is 2, date and time should appear in A3 and so on up to let's say A200.

I've tried to make this doing different loops.

https://github.com/Cuyer/excel/blob/main/add_click

```vb
Sub Add_Click()
    Dim countCell As Range
    Set countCell = ActiveSheet.Range("L13")
    countCell = countCell + 1
   
    Dim wb As Workbook
   
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        wb.Save
    Next wb
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Sub Add_Click()
   Dim countCell As Range, ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set countCell = ws.Range("L13")
   countCell.Value = countCell.Value + 1
   'use Offset() to find the date cell
   ws.Range("A1").Offset(countCell.Value,0) = Date

   Dim wb As Workbook
   
   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
       wb.Save
   Next wb
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function) function in VBA will give you the Date value of the current day.

Then you can just assign it to a range's value:

`Activesheet.Range("A" & countCell + 1).Value = Date`

I'm not sure if you mean the Date should appear in a single cell or in a number of cells equal to the value in "L13". The code above is for a single cell, but here is how you would do it for a number of cells:

`ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & countCell + 1).Value = Date`